# Comparing Daisy descriptors of two images

Tags: python, image-processing, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I am following http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.11.x/auto_examples/plot_daisy.html, but it's not very clear what does desc[0],desc[1] and desc[2] mean. I am trying to compare the descriptor vector of two images using Brutte Force or Flann matcher. But the size of the descriptor vectors of two images are not same.
Can anyone please suggest me the way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might reside the way that you are trying to access the feature vectors.

In the link that you posted for your example the variable descs is a 3 dimensional array, the first two dimension indicate which feature vector you want to access, while the third dimension is the actual descriptor vector. In other words, the way that you access all the feat vectors is through something like:

> descs[i][j]

In this particular example with the parameters that are predefined (step=180, radius=58, rings=2, histograms=6), you are building feature vectors with a **length of 104**.

The length of the vector comes from having 8 orientation bins for each of the 13 circular regions (#rings x #histograms + 1 where #rings=2, #histograms=6 for this particular example, 1 is for the central region) that are located within a radius of 58 pixel.

> Feat. Length = #bins x #regions = 8 x 13 = 104

Hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, so that means if the shape of vector is (2,3,104), it will imply that total keypoints/features identified are 6 (2*3), and we will get 6 descriptor vectors of length 104  for each of the keypoint detected right?
and can you suggest any descriptor matcher and the distance metric to compare these descriptor vectors? Like for sift there is flann matcher.

Comment: That is correct, that means you have 6 feat. vectors.
I don't know how to match this type of feature vectors but just found a face matching research based on daisy descriptor. The link to the paper is: http://www.eurecom.fr/en/publication/3185/download/mm-publi-3185.pdf